# Static files in ASP.NET MVC5 stock application are not cached with a 304

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net-mvc

Using VS 2013, I have created an MVC5 application just with bare settings. Nothing changed to the project and build and run the application with `BuildTable.EnableOptimizations` set to `true` in BuildConfig.

The issues is that static Stylesheets and JavaScript files which should be returned as 304 after the first request as they have a `Last-Modified` header.

Is there anything else need to be done to make these files cached and return with 304 with subsequent reloads?

Comment: Are you using standard IIS? Or IIS express? In case of later, try IIS

Comment: IISExpress. Let me try with IIS and check it. My bad, missed simple thing.

Comment: No luck, still the same http status of 200 in IE 11, chrome & firefox does caching of the scripts on client side, but in IE 11 the content is pulled from server, not sure why?